# Salesforce-Quip integration of custom objects?

Tags: custom-object, integration, quip

I'm looking at an option of integrating Quip with Salesforce and am particularly interested in bringing custom object information from Quip into Salesforce.
The only documentation available was about standard objects, and Quip support did not have any additional insights.

Has anyone done something similar and has any info on how to achieve this?